# Check for empty fields in Jekyll data files

Tags: jekyll

My data file is as follows:

```yaml
- title: Title  
  description: Lorem Ipsum .....  
  link: http://link.com  
  social: facebook  
  sociallink: http://facebook.com  

- title: Title2 
  description: Lorem Ipsum .....  
  link: http://link.com
```

The index.md page is as follows:

```
{% for member in site.data.info %}

##[{{ member.name }}]({{ member.link }})   

{{ member.description }}   

[{{ member.social }}]({{ socialLink }})

{% endfor %}
```

Some items don't have a `social` field or a `socialLink` field. I'd like not to print them out as `[]()`.

Is there some kind of tag to check if a field exists, like `{% if member has field %} // {% end if %}`?

Comment: Does `{% if member.social %}` work?

Comment: lol yeah =.= hahahahaha Thanks ^.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no special operator, the [`if` tag](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#if--else) can check if (ha) a variable exists:

```
{% if member.social %}
  {{ member.social }}
{% endif %}
```